# facebook share not showing all images in a thumbnail using og url

Tags: facebook, image, share, facebook-opengraph

Am using sharethis facebook share link in my website. When i try to share a post from my website the page contains large number of photos, but in facebook share preview it shows only three thumbnails.Am using following meta tags.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $post['title']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $post['description']; ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" />
```

While i debug using this link http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, it shows all the images.

Comment: Can you add a link to your page please?

Comment: @JacobAmerz http://mahoneyskateboards.com/entry/92/GO-SKATEBOARDING-DAY-NYC-RECAP

Comment: I think FB decided a while ago to show only a maximum of three images on the share/feed dialog any more – no matter if you explicitly declare more using meta elements or without meta tags there are more images on your page.

Comment: @CBroe, Any links where you found this information? Or what is the order of the photos?